# App Mis-calculated Checkmate?

Tags: checkmate

[image]

How is this checkmate? The King isn't even in check! Am I missing something, or did the chess app goof up?

Comment: Current position is definitely not a checkmate, but if it's white's turn then there's a mate in 2 after `Bh6+ Ke8 Rg8#.` Maybe it's a display bug, where a checkmate happened at some point and you undid a couple of moves but the "Checkmate" message remained.

Comment: @Phonon You're correct. The app shows "Checkmate" after undos.

Answer (score 3):

If the app first displayed checkmate in that position, then it miscalculated.

But as Phonon noted, the app could have displayed checkmate in a previous (future) position, and then you went back a few moves. In that case it's not a miscalculation per se, but just a bug in the UI.